# WebBrowser Control: Disable Cross Site XSS Filtering or another way to process JS in full on HTML

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, browser, xss

I am trying to use my web browser control to get retrieve date from a specific page, including all sub-page content.  Problem is some of the sub-pages are on a separate domain and thus I am getting a permission deigned error when i try to access the frame [through document.windows.frames(i).document].

Now I understand the reason this is happening as outlined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028.aspx.  However, unlike a user browsing a site who does not want javascript sniffing their history / cookies, I am physically opening my program and running the application for the purpose of this.

Is there any work around to do this, even if I have to manually change security settings?  I tried turning all my settings in IE to allow and still same error.  I will only be running the app locally and no one will be browsing on IE so I can literally change anything needed to get this to work (even install older version of IE which may allow it but can still handle JS processing).

Note the reason I am using web browser is a great majority of data I will be accessing is JS generated, so I need to access the DOM after JS processed / generated the HTML. Because of this, simply using SOCKETS to get the HTML is really not an option.  Even if I had the HTML, I still need some type of engine to process all of the DOM elements based off javascript.  If you know of an alternative to this, that is completely acceptable too!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a proxy on your server to fetch the data and you'll load it from your own domain into a hidden div and then you will be able to use JS to get the data you need from the HTML

Comment: i could see that working on a small scale, but if were collecting data from 100,000's of places thats a heck of a lot of domains to custom setup, especially if u dont even know them before hand =(

Comment: Kleino: Again we are realistically talking about doing it on very specific cases in order for that to work. A heck of a lot more would be involved to do that on a large scale. Example: there may be 3-4 iframes down I need to go, or 5-6 scripts I need to execute which also process another 2-3 scripts inside it.  I just don't see a proxy effect working.  You are also assuming cookies do not need to be passed, which in some cases is not true.  Is it possible to do it with a "proxy", maybe, but the amount of overhead work to work in all situations would be insane. I am on the right track though

Comment: overriding the WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite to update IInternetSecurity. Seems to be the only way to actually do this, and not any actual solid working examples really out there so gotta take bits and pieces from here and there / different languages to hopefully get a working product.


I do greatly appreciate the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic proxy page like this:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class TestPage : Page
{
    private WebRequest _request;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text;
        string url = Request["UrlToGet"];
        _request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (WebResponse response = _request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all you need to do is put the requested url in your QueryString or in the post data
and you will get the content of the page inside the string text

Answer (score 0):

A HyperText Application may be an option in situations like this.  HTA applications run inside their basic browser window, but with permissions of an executable.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information about HTAs.  Note that HTAs *do provide* security for non-application frames and iframes.