# Include a webpage inside a div

Tags: html, iframe

I have to include a webpage inside my webpage's div. I want somehting like `iframe` to be done with `DIV`. Basically, I will be providing a URL to my div and it has to open it inside itself... Do we have something like this in modern HTML? I cannot use frames as some browsers have issues with frames.

Comment: I suspect that you'll have fewer problems using an `iframe` than you will by recreating `iframe` functionality with a `div`. Which browsers are you targeting that have problems using `iframes` (or `frame`s)?

Comment: Couldnt find anything to vote down this is just a simple question because browsers like chrome doesnt allow interframe communications

Comment: Chrome allows interframe communications. It doesn't allow interdomain communications without CORS, but that's according to spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. You can't embed a complete HTML document inside another div element as this is a **block level element** and W3C has defined what could be included inside it.

But there is a workaround. Follow these steps:

1. Get the document using ajax (jQuery rocks, use that)
2. Extract the content of the `<body>` element and put it inside your `div` element
3. Get all links and script of `<head>` element and append them to the `<head>` element of your existing pgae.

Comment: I realize this is a year old, but I have the same requirement.  If you use this idea, will you have trouble with `id` attributes?  (You might have the same id on 2 of the pages you are 'combining')  Duplicate id's may mess up the browser and any `js` query code...

Comment: Can someone throw an example on how this is achieved. Total newbie to html/css here :/.

Answer (score 22):

Try using an `<object>` element:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px;">
    <object type="text/html" data="**URL to page**"
            style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browsers/versions does it compatible with?

Comment: I get 403 access denied when i use above approach , any possible reasons pleas e?

Comment: See [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object#Browser_compatibility) about compatibility

Answer (score 4):

you should use iframe. that's basically what iframes are for. if you stick with modern browsers in any case they don't have issues with iframes (not more than you'll have to face using div's instead)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframe or if you decide to use jQuery load function (http://api.jquery.com/load/) you need to avoid the cross script scripting problem - you need to create some sort of proxie take a look at this: [WebBrowser Control: Disable Cross Site XSS Filtering or another way to process JS in full on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477432/webbrowser-control-disable-cross-site-xss-filtering-or-another-way-to-process-js/6483485#6483485)

Answer (score 0):

It should have been in the question itself, but the OP has clarified the reason he does not want to use an `iframe` is  because interframe communication is not allowed. Well, that’s nothing a proxy + [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) can’t solve.

I believe there is simply no way to actually embed a full document within another one, retaining things like separation of styles and scripts and the like, without using frames in some sense.

Answer (score -1):

This is really an extension to Saeed's response.  To get around cross site scripting issues, you will have to write a script on your own server that does a CURL call for the webpage to be embedded.  Your javascript will then make a call to this script, passing the URL as a GET/POST parameter.

I agree with a lot of other people here that this is a case where you really should just use an iframe...  I believe you can set the iframe with no src tag and manually put the content inside it.  That would mean you don't need to take the steps Saeed suggested to break up the head and body.  However you still need the script I described to get around cross site scripting.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I agree with Frédéric Hamidi from above. Just embed an “object” inside a div and reference the URL of the other page in that object.

You can set all the styling for the second page on itself or in a separate CSS file.
That styling gets imported along with the page content without conflicting with the current pages style or scripts.

I tested Frédéric Hamidi’s theory on these browsers, all performed just fine.

•   Internet Explorer – v11

•   Microsoft Edge - v 84.0.522.59 (Official build) (64-bit)

•   Google Chrome – v84.0.4147.105

•   FireFox – v79.0

•   Brave – v1.11.104

•   Opera – v69.0.3686.95

•   Safari – v13